# Hammer not defined in angular universal

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-universal

I used hammerjs for swiping in angular5.It is not working while converting my app as angular universal.can anyone pls help me.my code is like below for hammer

```
var sliderManager = new Hammer.Manager(sliderEl);
 if (sliderManager) {
 sliderManager.add(new Hammer.Pan({ threshold: 0, pointers: 0 }));
```

Thanks

Comment: what is error you are getting ?

Comment: Cannot find name 'Hammer'

Comment: you might need "d.ts" file which is having type defined

Comment: Thanks.But Iam not getting.d.ts means?

Comment: have you done this : npm install --save angular-hammer

Comment: I have installed hammerjs.It was fine before converting it to angular universal

Comment: hi, follows the step in given answer ,  that is way to add types of hammer js in you angular project

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is you missing type , and you need to install it like as below

```
npm install @types/hammerjs --save-dev
```

add reference of hammerjs typings in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"types": [
  ...,
  "hammerjs"
]
```

if not working than , install hammerjs itself via npm:

```
npm i hammerjs
```

or follow this

1. npm install hammerjs --save-dev
2. npm install @types/hammerjs --save-dev
3. import 'hammerjs'; (in main.ts)

answer : https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material/issues/244#issuecomment-241600752

For windows not defined issue follow this : https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/930

Comment: build Error is fixed.But it gives \dist\server.js:153682
})(window, document, 'Hammer');
   ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined while running

Comment: @kamalav - follow this link for that : https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/930

Comment: @kamalav - is that worked , please do accept or upvote if helped

Comment: hi,Thanks,I upvoted this because this is fixed my build error.I am trying to fix runtime error.If it is fixed .I will mark it as accepted answer

Comment: @kamalav - so you are still getting windows ref error ?..i suggest better to post issue at there github page you will get answer soon if its complicated